# how to write a hql to get all records without permissions

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have three tables

```
Project
   id, name
ProjectAuthorization
   id,  project_id, user_id , permission
User
   id, name
```

Project.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProjectAuthorization> permissions;
```

User.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ProjectAuthorization> permissions;
```

ProjectAuthorization.java

```
@ManyToOne()
private Project project;
@ManyToOne()
private User user;
```

I want to get all projects that current user without any permissions,  how to write it by hibernate query?

**Update**

hql like this:

```
select p from Project as p left join p.permissions as pa where pa.user.id!=:userid and p.id not in (select pa2.project.id from ProjectAuthorization as pa2 where pa2.user.id=:userid)");
```

Comment: Do you have any association mapping between these tables?

Comment: yes, project have OneToMany permission, User also have OneToMany permission

Comment: Lets see the mappings them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example following query (also valid JPQL, no Hibernate specific constructs in use) can be used:

```
SELECT p
FROM Project p
WHERE p.id NOT IN
  (SELECT authorization.project.id
   FROM ProjectAuthorization authorization
   WHERE authorization.user = :currentUser)
```